# How to put asterisk sign at right top of text box

Tags: html

**here is my code:**

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_name" required/>
    <span style="color: red; background-position: right top;">*</span>

</div>
```

but that sign display under the textbox, how to fix the position of asterisk sign at top right.

Comment: I think the result is exactly as you wanted. Please clarify more if not

Comment: Instead of "span" use "sub". For more info - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp

Comment: it showing the same result as I mentioned earlier

Answer (score 0):

[Check this. i think u need it like same](http://www.cliptheme.com/preview/admin/clip-one/form_wizard.html). Use font awesome to put asterisk mark

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
        Username <i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Text Field" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check wether other elements or elemnt clarifications in your CSS have influence on the behavior of your code. Since the code as it is works just fine.

the use of "float" often dearanges code. So if you use float a lot it could be the cause. "display:block" or other displays can help avoiding those affections.

But as said befor you should clarify your problem more.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#marker {
  position: relative;
  left:-15px;
  top:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_name" required/>
    <span id="marker" style="color: red; background-position: right top;">*</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the replay but I want asterisk sign outside the textbox at top right corner.